# Oscillatory Behavior Solving Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

I would like to solve a 1-dimensional mass transport problem of the form:

$$\frac{\partial{c}}{\partial{t}}=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf{N}$$

where there are no homogeneous reactions and with initial and boundary conditions:

$$ c(t=0) = c_{bulk}$$

$$ c(y=0) = 0 $$

$$ c(y=\infty) = c_{bulk}$$

$c$ is concentration, $t$ is time, $\mathbf{N}$ is the flux, $y$ is the spatial coordinate, and $c_{bulk}$ is the bulk concentration

This problem can be re-written as an ordinary differential equation (ODE) using a similarity transform:

$$\frac{d\mathscr{N}}{d\eta}=2\eta\frac{dc}{d\eta}$$

where $\eta$ is defined as

$$\eta=\frac{y}{2\sqrt{Dt}}$$

where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.

The relationship between $\mathscr{N}$ and $\mathbf{N}$ is given by

$$\mathscr{N}=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{D}}\mathbf{N}=-\frac{dc}{d\eta}$$

when the flux $\mathbf{N}$ follows Fickian diffusion

$$\mathbf{N}=-D\nabla{c}$$

The transformed boundary conditions are

$$c(\eta=0) = 0$$

$$c(\eta=\infty) = c_{bulk}$$

($\eta = 6$ is used to approximate infinity; note the numerical solution compares favorably with the analytical solution for $\eta=6$.)

substituting $\mathscr{N}=-dc/d\eta$ into the transformed mass balance equation produces

$$-\frac{d^2c}{d\eta^2}=2\eta\frac{dc}{d\eta}$$

which conveniently has an analytical solution for these boundary conditions: $c(\eta)=c_{\infty} \cdot \mathrm{erf} (\eta)$.

My question deals with solving this problem numerically as a boundary-value problem.
Using central-differences to calculate the first and second spatial derivatives, i.e.

$$\frac{dc}{d\eta}=\frac{c_{j+1}-c_{j-1}}{2h}$$

$$\frac{d^2c}{d\eta^2}=\frac{c_{j+1}-2c_{j} + c_{j-1}}{h^2} $$

$ j = 1$
$$\frac{dc}{d\eta} = \frac{-3 c_j + 4 c_{j+1} - c_{j+2}}{2h}$$

$ j = NJ$
$$ \frac{dc}{d\eta} = \frac{3c_j - 4c_{j-1} + c_{j-2}}{2h} $$

I have no problem solving this equation: $-\frac{d^2c}{d\eta^2}=2\eta\frac{dc}{d\eta}$

However, I wish to segregate the equations and solve as a set of coupled first order ODEs:

$$\frac{d\mathscr{N}}{d\eta}=2\eta\frac{dc}{d\eta}$$

$$\mathscr{N}=-\frac{dc}{d\eta} $$

(2 first-order ODEs - still only need two boundary conditions), I get some oscillatory behavior in the solution which makes convergence difficult and sometimes practically impossible.

My question is what is causing this oscillatory behavior and how can I mitigate it?

Comment: You would need to give a little more detail, for instance the value $\eta_N$ that replaces infinity. Note that the Lipschitz constant has about that value, which requires $\eta_Nh\le 2$ for numerical stability. Violation of that bound can lead to large amplitudes of the heavily oscillating components in the Fourier decomposition picture.

Comment: $\eta_N = 6$, and to satisfy the condition $\eta_N h \le 2$, I need at least 19 nodes points $ 6 * (6/(NJ-1)) \le 2$ --> $NJ \ge 19$. That condition I am meeting.

Comment: So you start with $c(y,t)$ satisfying $c_t=Dc_{yy}$. Then you change to $u(η,t)=c(2\sqrt{Dt}η,t)$ so that $u_{η}=2\sqrt{Dt}c_{y}$ and $u_{ηη}=4Dtc_{yy}$ and $u_t=\sqrt{D/t}ηc_y+c_t$. Now demanding stationarity in $u$, $u_t=0$, gives the equation $$0=η/(2t)u_{η} + 1/(4t)u_{ηη},$$ which indeed resolves to your transformed equation.

Comment: $Lh\le 2$ gives for most methods the barest of numerical stability. For things that look like a solution you will need $Lh\le 0.5$ or smaller. And of course it has to be $L=2η_{NJ}$, as that is the largest value of the coefficient, for some reason I missed the factor $2$. So 19 nodes may indeed be not enough, try 37 and then about 150.

Comment: You could transform the first equation of the last system to $$\frac{d({\scr N}-2ηc)}{dη}=-2c.$$ The discretization via trapezoidal rule might be more logical in this form.

Comment: Solving ${\scr N}'=-2η{\scr N}$, $c'=-{\scr N}$ using the trapezoidal rule does not produce any oscillations. You would need to report more details on the implementation that produced the oscillation.